# MSSQL Convert an actual hex in a varchar string so I can convert to INT and Varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, hex

I have a hex value imported as a varchar, for example '0x400007'.  I want to be able to convert 0x40007 to other datatypes for analysis.

```
select convert(varbinary(max),0x400007)
```

Returns 0x400007 however the string

```
select convert(varbinary(max),'0x400007')
```

Returns 0x3078343030303037.  How can I get the literal string to return 0x40007? Ultimately, my goal is to use

```
select convert(int,0x400007)
```

and further manipulate the int value, 4194311 in this example, in other functions.  It's been a dogs age since I've had to think in hex so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x400007` and `'0x400007'` are not actually the same value. When you simply convert the `varchar` value that represents a `varbinary` value, it'll be convert to it's actual `varbinary` value, which (as you found out) is `0x3078343030303037`. `30` is `0`, `78` is `x`, `34` is `4`, `30` is `0` (notice you have multiple of them) and then finally `37` is `7`.

You need to use a style code, to let SQL Server know the `varchar` represents a `varbinary` and it'll convert it as you expect:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), '0x400007', 1);
```